# Transparent color background on image remove on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue where I put a transparent color background over an image, with the image partially showing, and I want the color to have an opacity of 0.0 (disappear) when the user hovers over it, revealing the image.

Here's my code:

```
#music{
    /*background-color: #13505B;*/
    background: url('../images/music.jpg'); 
}


#music::before{
    position:absolute;
    content: ""; 

    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;

    transition: background 0.5s ease; 
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(19, 80, 91, 0.7) !important;
}

#music:hover::before{
    background-color: rgba(19, 80, 91, 0.0) !important;
}
```

I haven't been able to get this effect working yet. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative;` to `#music`. I guess that was it. I just added a `background-color` for the lack of image.

```css
#music{
    background-color: deeppink;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
}


#music::before{
    position:absolute;
    content: ""; 

    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;

    transition: background 0.5s ease; 
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(19, 80, 91, 0.7);
}

#music:hover::before{
    background-color: rgba(19, 80, 91, 0.0);
}
```

```html
<div id="music"></div>
```